# Dynamically accounting for dependencies

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic

I am having difficulty developing an algorithm for my application. The application needs to be very flexible in order to account for multiple devices and multiple styles.

Here is one of the rules for ONE of the devices:

```
Only for styles 1,2,3,8,9,10
If slope = I2t
  Range: 2-24
  Step 0.5
If slope = I4t
  Range: 1-5
  Step 0.5
If slope = Mod Inv 
  Range: 0.1-5.0
  Step 0.1
If slope = Very Inv or Ext Inv
    Range 0.2-5.0
    Step 0.1

Ony for Styles 4,5,6,7
If slope = I2t
    Range: 2-24
    Step 0.5
If slope = I4t
    Range: 1-5
    Step 0.5
If slope = IEC-A
    Range: 0.05 - 1.00
    Step 0.05
If slope = IEC-B
    Range: 0.10 - 1.00
    Step 0.05
If slope = IEC-C
    Range: 0.20-1.00
    Step 0.05
```

Now I could code this up for this specific device, but there are multiple devices with a different set of statements. Currently I am reading in these values from a file. This allows me to update the number of devices the program supports without changing code and therefore reduces the maintence.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your post doesn't give much detail away, but it does say that you have a solution already.  What's wrong with your current approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-way to save the input values and corresponding config settings and then just look in dictionary.
Something like this:

```
struct ConfigKey
{
     public readonly int Style;
     public readonly string Slope;
     public ConfigKey(int style, string slope) 
     {
        this.Style = style;
        this.Slope= slope;
     }
     public override bool Equals(object obj)
     {
         if (!(obj is ConfigKey))
         {
             return false;
         }
         ConfigKey other = (ConfigKey)obj;
         return this.Style == other.Style && this.Slope == other.Slope;
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return Style.GetHashCode() ^ Slope.GetHashCode();
     }
}
struct Config
{
    String  Range {get; set;}
    Double Step { get; set; }
}
Dictionary<ConfigKey, Config> conf = new Dictionary<ConfigKey, Config>();

public Config GetConfig(int style, string slope)
{
    return conf[new ConfigKey(style, slope)];
}
```